# How to check substring in Bourne Shell?

Tags: sh

I wanna test whether a string has "substring". Most answers online is based on Bash. I tried

```
if [ $string == "*substring*" ]
```

which was not working. Currently

```
if echo ${string} | grep -q "substring"
```

worked. Is there any other better way.

Comment: Your original attempt requires bash's builtin `[[`, so probably won't work for you.

Comment: yeah, so do you know any better approach?

Comment: Nope. All improvements I can think of would only work in Bash. There is really nothing wrong with using `grep -q` though, except that is starts a separate subprocess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using POSIX compliant [parameter-expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) and with the classic [test-command](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/classictest).

```
#!/bin/sh

substring=ab
string=abc

if [ "$string" != "${string%"$substring"*}" ]; then
    echo "$substring present in $string"
fi
```

(or) explicitly  using the `test`  operator as

```
if test "$string" != "${string%$substring*}" ; then
```

Comment: I'm not sure how to make this completely robust, though. You need to at least quote the expansion of `$substring` for this to work for `string=a*b` and `substring=*`, for example. `[ "$string" != "${string%"$substring"*}" ]` (This might be sufficient, though.)

Comment: @chepner: Thanks! Updated!

Comment: Also keep in mind that regex meta characters like `'*'` need quoting in `$substring`.

Answer (score 5):

**In a POSIX-features only shell you won't be able to do *general* pattern or regex matching *inside a conditional* without the help of an *external utility***.

That said:

- [Kenster's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40772200/45375) shows how to use the **branches of a `case ... esac` statement for pattern matching**.
- [Inian's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40771648/45375) shows how to **match *indirectly*** inside a conditional, using **patterns as part of *parameter expansions***.

Your own `grep` approach is certainly an option, though you should double-quote `${string}`:

```
if echo "${string}" | grep -q "substring"; ...
```

A slightly more efficient way is to use the [`expr` utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/expr.html), but note that per POSIX it is limited to [BREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (*basic* regular expressions), which are limited:

```
string='This text contains the word "substring".'

if expr "$string" : ".*substring" >/dev/null; then echo "matched"; fi
```

Note that the regex - the 3rd operand - is implicitly anchored at the *start* of the input, hence the need for `.*`.

`>/dev/null` suppresses `expr`'s default output, which is the length of the matched string in this case. (If nothing matches, the output is `0`, and the exit code is set to `1`).

Answer (score 1):

If you're just testing for substrings (or anything that can be matched using filename wildcards) you can use `case`:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
    case "$line" in
    *foo*) echo "$line" contains foo ;;
    *bar*) echo "$line" contains bar ;;
    *)     echo "$line" isnt special ;;
    esac
done

$ ./testit.sh
food
food contains foo
ironbar
ironbar contains bar
bazic
bazic isnt special
foobar
foobar contains foo
```

This is basic Bourne shell functionality. It doesn't require any external programs, it's not bash-specific, and it predates POSIX. So it should be pretty portable.

Comment: ++ for a true POSIX-compliant pattern-matching option that I've missed in my answer (it now links to yours too).

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, not if you are trying to use vanilla sh, without Bash extensions. On many modern systems, `/bin/sh` is actually a link to `/bin/bash`, which provides a superset of `sh`'s functionality (for the most part). Your original attempt would have worked with Bash's builtin `[[` extended test command: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031